# Puppet custom recursive directory synchronization

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to implement a custom recursive directory synchronization resource in Puppet. What I need to do is the following.

I have a YAML file with the list of hostnames and the list of directories that should exist on each hostname inside, say, `/var/lib/my_app` directory (`deployment.yml`):

```
host_1:
  - DIR_1
  - DIR_5
host_5:
  - DIR_7
host_6:
  - DIR_2
  - DIR_3
  - DIR_9
```

On the master I have a directory that contains all of those `DIR_*` sub-directories. Each subdirectory contains some files. What I'm trying to achieve is to synchronize all the nodes according to the `deployment.yml`, so that `/var/lib/my_app` on `host_1` only contains `DIR_1` and `DIR_5`, but does not contain `DIR_7`, `DIR_2`, `DIR_3`, `DIR_9`, and so on.

I tried to do this using the ignore variable for file type, but this does not remove the directories from the node if I remove them from deployment.yml. I tried to write a custom function to remove them afterwards, but it does not seem to work inside my manifest. I also wanted to implement a custom type, but it seems to be too complicated.

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up implementing this with Ruby DSL

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the 'purge' parameter for the file type. You would set this at the file resource for /var/lib/my_app.

Snippet from "puppet describe file":

```
- **purge**
    Whether unmanaged files should be purged. This option only makes
    sense when managing directories with `recurse => true`.

    * When recursively duplicating an entire directory with the `source`
      attribute, `purge => true` will automatically purge any files
      that are not in the source directory.
    * When managing files in a directory as individual resources,
      setting `purge => true` will purge any files that aren't being
      specifically managed.

    If you have a filebucket configured, the purged files will be uploaded,
    but if you do not, this will destroy data.  Valid values are `true`,
    `false`.
```

Comment: You need to be careful that you don't have some files in the dirs that you don't want managed, because they will be purged also.  It basically says that in the snippet above, but people seem to skip it (including me).

Comment: @Ger Apeldoorn To be able to do this with purge I need to pass the list of subdirectories I want to exist to source, but I'm not sure I can do this.